# Return the index of chaged handle on jquery-ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have a jquery ui slider:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    values: [ 10, 25,45,176 ],
    max: 190,
    change: function( event, ui ) {  
        var index = $("#slider span").index(ui.handle);
        $( "#index" ).text( "That was handle index #" + index );
    }
});
```

I want to return the index of the changed single handle. But the handle object returns all spans (handles).

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the `change` event function, `ui.handle` is the element that was changed. Therefore, use `$(ui.handle).index()` to access the index of the element. Note: The index is zero-based.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4eqcez98/)

```
$("#slider").slider({
    values: [ 10, 25,45,176 ],
    max:190,
    change: function( event, ui ) {  
        var index = $(ui.handle).index();
        $("#index").text( "That was handle index #" + index );
    }
});
```

Comment: that returns -1 for all handles.

Comment: @behnamizadi I had a typo, see the update. It doesn't return `-1` in the example I posted.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone seeing this after the [March 2015 patch](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/pull/1473) that added the `handleIndex` property to the `ui` object, if you need the index of the current handle, you can just use, for example:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    values: [10, 25, 45, 176],
    max: 190,
    change: function(event, ui) {  
        var index = ui.handleIndex;
        $("#index").text("That was handle index #" + index);
    }
});
```